# Possible to carry a whole branding process by yourself?

Tags: branding, research

Probably beginner graphic designers interests start around logo creation. Then probably shift towards visual identity, then branding.

My interests started directly from logo to branding, *now I kind of regret that*. Because, as a beginner, I found out that branding it's much more than the logo and visuals. Branding includes marketing research, tone of speech, customer services and how employees treat you, customer experience, and probably a lot more I'm not aware of.

Knowing this, **the branding process seems like a really, REALLY intensive research work**, more than I thought. It's kind of overwhelming.

So my question is; *Can you design/create a brand all by yourself as a beginner?* Where can I learn to go solo on a branding process? Should I keep myself with Corporate Visual Identity first, then move to Branding?

Comment: I've always heard brand identity as a visual element to the company. I have never heard of branding including "customer service, market research, etc." That seems outside the scope of a graphic designer and the graphic designer stack exchange.

Comment: Here is an article that got me thinking into this: https://blog.jcimarketing.com/business-marketing/the-difference-between-visual-identity-and-branding

Comment: Get an actual book, articles like this are sometimes just a collection of keywords to attract search engine traffic, which dillutes the meaning of the topic.

Comment: What book do you have in mind?

Comment: Not sure if this is the most relevant but these come to mind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wally_Olins#Books

Comment: I guess a brand does speak to an overall experience. But as a Graphic Designer, if someone comes to you to help create a brand for them, you wouldn't be expected to help them with the companies customer experience procedure. As a Graphic Designer, you would be creating the logo, website, flyers, business cards or even the brand guidelines/visual identity. You're asking way more of what a brand is than what a Graphic Designer actually deals with.

Comment: That's a relive to read, but on most sites (if not all of them) that I read about the "Branding Process" include market research, and other many marketing related topics outside our field. I was kind of assimilating/understanding that the graphic designer also needs to do market research. I hope I'm wrong. If that's the case, then a Graphic Designer would just be in charge of the visual identity? Nothing more, nothing else?

Comment: You would do market research that helps with creating the visual identity of the brand. Example, if I am tasked with creating a logo for a girls toy company. I would probably use colors like pink and purple instead of orange and brown. You base your design on the target audience and the type of look that you want the brand to convey. In my experience, a Graphic Designer would only be working on the visual identity for a company.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do a branding job solo, but it also kind of depends on the job and your experience.

Then, branding can mean different things, for some clients it may just be a logo and a website. Other times a branding job can mean so much you need a team to deliver.

Just stick to what you can do.